# FingerPaint on Android and OpenGL-ES

Tags: android, opengl-es, touch-event

I am developing an android game and I would like to implement a method that onTouchEvent follows the finger of the user and along that path draws a line.

There is an example on the SDK, though it is using Canvas. How can I do the same on OpenGL-ES?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Queue up touch points and connect them using [`GL_LINE_STRIP`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glDrawElements.xml).

Answer (score 0):

You can also create GL_POINTS with the touchDown event